# Uncaught (in promise) Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new to React JS, trying to implement routing to my news app. I am keep on getting following error (I am using React Router v4 https://reacttraining.com/react-router)

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at Object.onlyChild [as only] (onlyChild.js:33)
    at Router.render (Router.js:99)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:796
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:795)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:822)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:362)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:258)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)
```

Here is my route file

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App.js';
import SourceNews from './SourceNews';


const Routes = () => (

    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/news/source/:id" component={SourceNews} />
        </div>
    </Router>
);


export default Routes;
```

I tried following this react router verison 4 tutorial but nothing seems to work

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Thanks

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './Routes.js';
import NewsList  from './NewsList';
import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { sources: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en&apiKey=c0f3800ecd5e42f5b1f5bc0e2902bddb')
            .then(result=> result.json())
            .then(json =>  {
                this.setState({sources: json.sources});
            });
    }

    render() {

        const sources = this.state.sources;
        // console.log(sources)
        return (

            <div>
                <Header />
                <NewsList sources={sources} />
            </div>
        )

    }

}

export default App;
```

**Update:**

Solved it by referring this article https://www.sigient.com/blog/movie-listings-application-with-react-router-v-4

Comment: I think would be useful to see what App.js does. And why wrapping routes in a div?

Comment: @MattiaGalati Removing the <div> wrapper also gives the same issue

Comment: Seems that App.js does not export class.

Comment: @MattiaGalati it is exporting .. see at the end of the file

Comment: You include Routes.js in App.js and App.js in Routes.js, may be it caused problem

Comment: Please share what your other components Header and NewsList look like.

Comment: @DevendraVerma sorry, didn't see the scrollbars.

Comment: @donquixote yes, That was the issue, solved it by following this article https://www.sigient.com/blog/movie-listings-application-with-react-router-v-4

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the order of your routes?

```
<div>
 <Route path="/news/source/:id" component={SourceNews} />
 <Route path="/" component={App} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrapped your routes inside a  in 'Routes.js' file. However,
i personally think you need to update your react-router version as you are using old version of react router, i would suggest you to use react-router 4 as it works great and is less confusing. After updating the react router you can update your code as following:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss } from 'react-router';
...
...
const Routes = () => {
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Match exactly pattern="/" component={App} />
            <Match pattern="/news/source/:id" component={SourceNews} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
}
```